# Bootstrap can't select checkbox on iPhone

Tags: iphone, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I can't select my checkboxes when I'm previewing on an iPhone. There's just one checkbox at the end of my document that DOES work, which is confusing me. The ones that don't work have this markup:

```
 <div id="advancedsearch-column" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
     <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">
       Brand 1
      </label>
    </div>
 </div>
```

The one that does work has this markup:

```
<div class="form-inline">
 <div class="checkbox no_margin">
   <label>
   <input type="checkbox"> On special
   </label>
 </div>
```

There is a form tag surrounding everything. I tried adding a .form-inline class to the faulty checkboxes but it didn't seem to help. The checkboxes work fine on desktop.

Comment: Will you provide the link to your site? These work in an iPhone on a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/gjap46La/

Comment: I can't because it's only visible in my office's network. I ended up solving the problem. Apparently, I had to specify col-xs (not just col-sm-) on one of the div's. I see problem arising often (mobile version misbehaving if I don't specify the col-xs), why is that?

Comment: Without seeing the entire project, it is hard to know.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to see 100% what is going on since you are only providing a small fragment of code.

I have seen this issue when you have columns in your bootstrap grid that do not add up to 12. Try removing the col-xs-12 class and see if it works.